# Evaluate $∫ydx+zdy+xdz$ where C is intersection of $x+z=a$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

Tags: vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

> Evaluate $∫ydx+zdy+xdz$ where C is intersection of $x+z=a$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$

I am using Stoke's Theorem to find the integral. I could solve the first half

> $\operatorname{curl}\text{ }F = -\hat{\textbf{i}} -\hat{\textbf{j}} -\hat{\textbf{k}}$

> Normal Vector N = $\frac{\hat{\textbf{i}}+\hat{\textbf{k}}}{\sqrt2}$

Ultimately I end up with having to find surface integral of $ds$. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done stokes theorem, so apologies if I make any error or whatnot.

The boundary curve is given by [image]

we can choose any surface that has this boundary. I'll go for the plane since it is most simple where $z=a-x$ with restrictions on the ellipse boundary.

You calculated the curl to be $\langle -1, -1, -1\rangle$ and the normal vector denotes positive orientation so we are good.

Thus we have $$\int_C\overrightarrow{\textbf{F}}\cdot\text{ d}\overrightarrow{\textbf{r}}=\iint_S\operatorname{curl }\overrightarrow{\textbf{F}}\cdot\text{ d}\overrightarrow{\textbf{S}}=\iint_D\langle -1, -1, -1\rangle\cdot\nabla f\text{ d}A$$
where $D$ is the 2D shadow of the ellipse boundary on the $x-y$ plane and $$\nabla f=\nabla\left(z-a+x\right)=\langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle$$
[image]

Now we have $$\iint_D\langle -1, -1, -1\rangle\cdot\langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle\text{ d}A=-2\iint_D\text{ d}A$$

We just need to calculate the area of the ellipse given by the equation $$\frac{x^{2}}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}}\le1$$ so this is just $$\pi\cdot \frac{a}{2}\cdot \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So if I havent made a mistake the answer should just be $$-2\cdot\frac{a^2\pi}{2\sqrt2}=-\frac{a^2\pi}{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Yep that was the final answer. What were the tools you used for the geometric representation? (And thanks for the solution btw)

Comment: @Vineethbharadwaj I used geogebra and desmos. I'm glad my skills arent that rusty lol. if that solved ur problem it would be nice if you mark my answer as correct :P